# PDF order table header

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, pdf

I am trying to reorder the table header on the order PDF, but I can't find the file anywhere. It's not in the Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf. I managed to trace down and modify everything, but this part is somewhere else.

[image]

Any idea where else can this code be?

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/firegento/firegento-pdf, might solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

The order doesn't have a PDF, but if you mean the invoice or shipment they both have a method `_drawHeader` that outputs the headers, the item itself is rendered in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Items_Invoice_Default` or `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Items_Shipment_Default` by the method `draw`

Comment: Yes, this draws the header for the invoice and the shipment. I'm talking about the PDF file that is generated when you press the PRINT button on the order page in the backend.

Comment: Double checked on a clean install with sample data but a standard order doesn't have a PDF as far as I can see. Could it be a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm talking about the PDF file that is generated when you press the PRINT button on the order page in the backend

It looks like you've mistaken the "print" **HTML** template for a PDF, which it isn't.

The template can be found in [template/sales/order/print.phtml](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/print.phtml)
.